# Wordpress throws an error when loading http_headers_1.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amazon-web-services

This bug is very recent and seemed to appear out of nowhere.  The console displays the following error:

> VM737:1 GET http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forton/http_headers_1.js

It also seems to sprout in every Wordpress admin page.

I have tried to search the entire wordpress code base for the amazonaws, forton, etc.  but could not find what is sending this request to the .js

I searched the internet for the error but only found a korean site with little information.

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 10):

It's Malware effect.
Try to check the extentions installed in your browser.
Ex. "HTTP Headers" had become malware recently.

Comment: Wow!  At first I could not believe it, but it's true.  The culprit really was the chrome "HTTP Headers" extension.  I would never think that since I got it from the official Chrome Web Store.  Well, living and learning... Thanks so much for your help Kobake.

Comment: I would never have figured that out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any info on what the malware effects were? searches on HTTP Headers malware only yields results in japanese.

Comment: http_headers_1.js might be injected by the extension, but the server script file has already been removed so I couldn't research the actual behavior of the scripts.

Comment: I can only say that the injection way of the extention was as evil, so the injected script also should be evil, I think.

I saved the extention code here for research.
https://github.com/kobake/http-headers-archives-for-research

Answer (score 1):

Yes I also removed the chrome HTTP Headers extention and it went away. thank you

Comment: HTTP Headers caused this problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. The sponsored by popup occurred twice this morning, once on a Wordpress site (on my imac) and once on a basic HTML site (on my macbook pro). In both instances I was using the Chrome browser and both computers had the HTTP Headers extension installed.

I right-clicked on the popup and selected "Inspect element" which showed the javascript file for the popup: http://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/forton/http_headers_1.js

That confirmed it was coming from the HTTP Headers extension, so I disabled it by going to Chrome/Preferences. That resolved the issue.